# How to setup GDB integration in Visual Studio 2019+ for the local machine?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, gdb

For Visual Studio 2015 there is a dedicated "GDB Debugger Extension". Apparently its actual name in the marketplace misleadingly is "Visual C++ for IoT Development" but explicitly listed in its description is:

> This extension provides a makefile project enables you to debug your native C/C++ code [...] locally on Windows.

[[1]](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/announcing-the-vs-gdb-debugger-extension/)[[2]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-3toI8L3Oug)[[3]](https://Visual%20C++%20for%20IoT%20Development)

For Visual Studio 2019 no such extension exists, but the Visual Studio Installer offers a component of the same name. Said component does not provides a project type whose name contains "GDB" (or any other recognisable identifier) and checking the available debuggers I see no entry "*GDB*" either.

These are the debuggers listed in my instance:

- Local Windows Debugger
- Remote Windows Debugger
- Web Browser Debugger
- Web Service Debugger

Here is [a Microsoft Learn article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/linux/create-a-new-linux-project?view=msvc-160) detailing how to debug remote Linux projects using a local instance of GDB (among other variants). It lists as its sole prerequisite the workload "Linux development with C++" which I have installed including all optional components.

Like with the older extension, this should provide me with a "*GDB*" debugger ("Remote GDB Debugger" in [this screenshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/linux/deploy-run-and-debug-your-linux-project?view=msvc-160#debug-your-linux-project)).

How do I get that entry? How can I debug a local, MinGW64-built executable with a local GDB in Visual Studio?

(I can already use gdb in a CLI, but I would like the comfort of the GUI.)

If it becomes easier in later versions of Visual Studio, I can upgrade.